# Could I abort the install process on Ubuntu Software?

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, 16.04

I rarely install applications from Ubuntu Software. I usually install applications from terminal or GDebi.

In previous versions of Ubuntu Software Center, I can abort the installation process.

[image]

But in GNOME Software, I can't abort install process.

Then, is there a way to abort install process from Ubuntu Software?

Answer (score 1):

#### Cancellation isn't supported now.

It's a pending [feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764672) on GNOME's bug tracker (with nothing related on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software)). There's no opposition to it (but then again, there's not much activity at all related to that request).

Even if it does get implemented in a later version, I'm not sure the feature will be backported to Ubuntu 16.04. Consider [filing a bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+filebug) linking to the upstream bug report to notify Ubuntu devs of the request.