# Cant cancel the installation from the software center in 16.04

Tags: software-center, 16.04, software-uninstall

[image: 1st image] , [image: 2nd image]

I Upgraded to 16.04. I thought I'd try out the new software center. but this takes ages to complete. I want to cancel it.

Comment: If it ever gets answered, dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/761301/could-i-abort-the-install-process-on-ubuntu-software